# .htaccess combination redirect/ hide subfolder from url AND force insertion of "www" to url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I pretty much have this working. My problem is, as soon as I click on any link inside of the site, the subfolder name is added to the url. The modifications I have made to the htaccess file are all in the root directory, the one in the site directory is the standard joomla htaccess file. I am not sure if that is messing it up. Here is an example of the code.

To rephrase, I type the url into the browser "domain.com" The htaccess does its' job and changes that to "www.domain.com" automatically. I know that it is routing to the subfolder, because I can see the actual site. Then I click on the "Home" button as an example. The URL then shown in the address bar is "www.domain.com/site"

```
##### Redirect non-www to www -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
##### Redirect non-www to www -- END

##### Subfolder redirect --BEGIN
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ site/index.php [L]
##### Subfolder redirect --END
```

I would be happy to post the entire htaccess file if needed, but I can tell you that through changing these two entries into it, I have gotten the site to where it is now. I have quite a few "security" measures in the file.

EDIT:
I should have put this in from the beginning, this is my attempt to redirect away from direct calls to the index.php. I just noticed that it may be fighting with my other redirect.

```
##### Redirect index.php to / -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http%2://www.domain.com/ [R,L]
##### Redirect index.php to / -- END
```

EDIT 2:I have been constantly dumping my web cache from my browser for testing. My site seems to be  running very slow right upon first connection and there is almost nothing on it as far as content. Have I added something that is requesting too much?